# How do i solve the "Undefined" issue with my Jquery Ajax web service call

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, web-services

Here is my JS code

```
function testService(test) {
var data = "{param2:\"" + test + "\"}";
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "WebService1.asmx/HelloWorld",
    dataType: "json",
    data: data,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function (response) {
        alert(response.d);
    },
    error: function(response) {
        alert(response.d);
    }
});
}
```

and my web method.

```
/// <summary>
/// Summary description for WebService1
/// </summary>
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class WebService1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public string HelloWorld(string val)
    {
        Service1 service1 = new Service1();
        Person person = service1.HelloWorld(val);
        return person.name;
    }
}
```

This seems to work fine if i attempt to call the web service method without a parameter, but once i try to pass data into the data value as a parameter i get "Undefined"

Comment: `var data = {param2: test };`

Comment: @ArunPJohny still undefined,

Comment: you have to change  (string val) to (string param2)

Comment: @naathon yeah that seems to work, thank you, you can put that in the answers so i can mark it if you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

param name in c# has to match the json object key(s)

```
public class WebService1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public string HelloWorld(string param2)
    {
        Service1 service1 = new Service1();
        Person person = service1.HelloWorld(val);
        return person.name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please take look in the javascript data and the helloworld method parmeter both need to be in same(words).

```
public class WebService1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public string HelloWorld(string param2)
    {
        Service1 service1 = new Service1();
        Person person = service1.HelloWorld(param2);
        return person.name;
    }
}
```